# r shiny rsconnect direct upload fails with missing PKI package records

Tags: r, shiny, pki

I have a shiny app running locally. I want to upload the files to the shiny server with rsconnect. Here's the code I use (with tokens and secrets xxxed out)

```
    rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name = 'nutrientmodeling',
                               token = 'xxx',
                               secret = 'xxx/')
rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = paste(getwd(),"nutrientModeling", sep = "/"))
```

I have rsconnect 0.7 and PKI version 0.1-5 installed. PKI was installed from a downloaded version with

```
install.packages("PKI_0.1-5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

that downloads the openssl headers.

When I run the code above, I get the following error message.

```
Error : Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages:
- 'PKI'
```

What do I need to change for rsconnect to find these records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to version 0.8 of rsconnect and a new version of PKI solved the problem. The new version of rsconnect is on CRAN but the new version of PKI is currently only on GitHub. Here's how to get it - `install_github("s-u/PKI")`. I 'think' it has the same version number as the PKI version on CRAN, which doesn't install, at least for me on my Mac.

This latest version gets the Apple openssl headers and puts them someplace where PKI can find them and rsconnect can then find the PKI package records.